# Optimise logic to partially match 2 array items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, data-structures, frontend

I have two arrays and want to match them partially( i.e. some elements of the first array should be present in the second array but not all). I have a solution but I feel I could use a more efficient one. Here is the use case:

```
const array_1 = [ 7, 6 ];
const array_2 = [ 4, 6 ,7, 2, 9 ];

const isSomeItemMatched = array_1.some( item => array_2.includes(item) );
const isAllItemMatched = array_1.every( item => array_2.includes(item) );

const isPartiallyMatched = !isAllItemMatched && isSomeItemMatched;
```

Please let me know if there is an optimized way of doing it.

Comment: Are both arrays guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: No, they would not be sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is fine for small arrays. If they get larger, you'll benefit from turning one into a set:

```js
const array_1 = [ 7, 6 ];
const array_2 = [ 4, 6 ,7, 2, 9 ];

function isPartialMatch(a, b) {
    const setA = new Set(a);
    return b.some(x => setA.has(x)) && b.some(x => !setA.has(x));
}

console.log(isPartialMatch(array_1, array_2));
```